# get object under frame using powershell v3

Tags: powershell, frame

i was tested manipulate ie using powershell v3 
but i hav trouble access object under frame

```
#url set
$Url = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_cols"

#open ie
$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$IE.visible = $true; 
$IE.navigate($url); 

#get first frame
$frm = @($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('frame'))[0]

#get h3 in frames[0]
$frm.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('h3') | foreach {
    echo $_.innerHTML
}
```

i`m using contentWindow, contentDocument and etc....

is there a way to access inner object of frames?